# retrieving FormData as its original form

Tags: javascript, next.js, frontend, multipartform-data, form-data

Today, while working on a project which uses
below flow for creating new **post** in website

[Client] ---> FormData --> [FrontEnd Server] ---> FormData -->[Backend Server] --> save post

I have some form-data sent from client using fetch to frontend server

ex..

**Client.js**

```js
let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('title', 'How to resolve Issue');
form_data.append('descr', '<p>The tips are mentioned in Home page!</p>');
form_data.append('image', uploaded_image);
fetch(`${FRONTEND_SERVER_URL}`, {method: 'POST', body: form_data})
```

Where form_data is an instance of FormData object

but on my server when i try to retrieve same form_data, i can't

ex..
**NextServer.js**

```js
export default async function handler(req, res){
    ...
    console.log(req.body);
    ...
}
```

I Got Something like,

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryJzNYHjUhaXw7Qpnx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

How to resolve Issue
------WebKitFormBoundaryJzNYHjUhaXw7Qpnx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="descr"

<p>The tips are mentioned in Home page!</p>
```

So can you help me to get actual FormData sent from the client instead of raw data(string)

Answer (score 0):

FormData uses multipart/form-data format. That is not a simple POST request with a body. It is generally used for uploading files, that's why it needs special handling. As an alternative, you could use JSON

Comment: yes this can, but what if i want to attach image to that formData, in that case application/json seems useless, any other idea?